# How to put a text element in a Win2D - CanvasSvg at runtime (in UWP using CanvasSvgTextElement)?

Tags: c#, svg, canvas, uwp, win2d

A want to write text to a Win2d CanvasSvg document however I am unable to find any example at all on how to to this. I have already drawn some basic shapes but I'm stuck on text. The Class is described at:
https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Svg_CanvasSvgTextElement.htm
I'm not sure if the Win2d CanvasSvg even supports normal Svg text as an attempt to load a simple text file in svg (which worked ok with Chrome) failed to show anything when loaded (using the Win2D sample on the GitHub site & swapping the file for loading).

A google search for CanvasSvgTextElement gives only 7 results! As you can in the bit of code below, I am out of my depth!

```
        string myTest = "<text x=\"100\" y=\"100\" text=\"Hello World\" />"; 
        CanvasSvgTextElement testElement = new CanvasSvgTextElement( //something goes here - how to find?// );
        svgDocument.Root.CreateAndAppendTextChildElement( //what to put here ?//);
```

Comment: The `CreateAndAppendTextChildElement` method requires a sting as the parameter. And  
the `CanvasSvgTextElement` object is generated by the `CreateAndAppendTextChildElement` method. You can't directly create it.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried various strings but no luck. I also used the Win2D sample on the GitHub to import a svg file with working text (text on a path) then to save the same file again. The text wasn't shown in the Win2D sample program and the text was stripped out of the sample.svg when saved by the sample program. I think my conclusion is that I am using the wrong tool to add text in an svg file programmatically and I have now decided just to create the svg directly by writing a file - rather than using Win2D svg, and then maybe use the WebView control to view the created svg graphic.